# How to set wordpress post title as image alt if not defined?

Tags: wordpress

I've many images in post contents, most of it doesn't have alt value.
is there any function to set post title as image alt.
I tried this function but it is not working.

```
function add_alt_tags($content)
{
        global $post;
        preg_match_all('/<img (.*?)\/>/', $content, $images);
        if(!is_null($images))
        {
                foreach($images[1] as $index => $value)
                {
                        if(!preg_match('/alt=/', $value))
                        {
                                $new_img = str_replace('<img', '<img alt="'.get_the_title().'"', $images[0][$index]);
                                $content = str_replace($images[0][$index], $new_img, $content);
                        }
                }
        }
        return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_alt_tags', 99999);
```